# How do I make a Running Total?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query made that takes all invoices from a specific customer and it shows all the payment information and current balance, as shown in the image of excel Ex: **Img1**

The idea is to add the **missing values** in the column **balance** Ex:

**Missing Value** is
0 + 518820 = **518820 Balance**;
518820 + 2777750 = **796570 Balance**
And so on ...

[image: Imagem em Excel IMG1]

Here are my scripts that I created to do the exercise. THE TABLES THAT ARE BEING WORKED ARE **BILLING (ft)** AND **CURRENT ACCOUNT (cc)**

```
SELECT ft.nmdoc, ft.fno, ft.fdata,  ISNULL(cc.deb,cc.cred) "Valor Doc",  ISNULL(cc.debf,cc.credf)Valor_Pago,
ISNULL((cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf)) Valor_em_Falta, 
ISNULL(++(cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf)) Saldo,
--ISNULL(SUM(@saldo ),0),
ft.pdata Dt_Vencimento 

FROM cc RIGHT JOIN  ft ON cc.ftstamp=ft.ftstamp 

where ft.nome ='JOAQUIM TESTE & FILHO,LDA'

GROUP BY ft.nmdoc, ft.fno, ft.fdata,ft.pdata ,cc.deb,cc.cred,cc.debf,cc.credf

order by ft.fdata
```

[image: SQL]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/860966/2029983) If not, why not? Sample data and expected results (not images) will help us help you if so as well.

Comment: I'm lost.  There is no column called "balance".

Comment: Thank you very much, for the indication of the link, it works perfectly. @Larnu